# Clothes arithmetic

Tags: calculation-puzzle

Can you tell how do these equations work?

> Glove + Pants = Jacket
>
> Sock + Skirt = Trousers
>
> Sweatshirt - Shoe = Jeans
>
> Coat - Boxers = Boot
>
> Sandal + Trousers = Tanktop

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe that this is

> Addition based on number of holes.

Glove + Pants = Jacket

> 1 + 3(two legs and torso) = 4(two arms, torso, and head)

Socket + Skirt = Trousers

> 1 + 2(torso and legs) = 3

Sweatshirt - Shoe = Jeans

> 4 - 1 = 3

Coat - Boxers = Boot

> 4 - 3 = 1

Sandal + Trousers = Tanktop

> 1 + 3 = 4

Comment: Sandals definitely have more than one hole, but this is probably correct

Comment: @monoRed Works better with *holes where body parts can go through* :-)

Comment: The kind of sandals i imagine are either flip flops, which have 3 holes (barely holes, as it's a stretch to say that flip flops have an "inside") or indoor sandals, which in my experience have a strap where your foot goes in and the toes can stick out of the end. I suppose the sandals you had in mind are like bunny slippers, with a closed end, but I'll admit I've never heard those referred to as "sandals".

Comment: My sandals have 5 holes :-)